# dotLiquid: modulo-calculation not working as expected

Tags: c#, template-engine, liquid, modulo, dotliquid

So I'm using [dotLiquid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotLiquid) (1.8.0) in my Project to create some HTML-Templates which are used to create PDFs via [EO.pdf](http://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/pdf/htmltopdf/overview.aspx)

So basically, I want to check if the given dates of an array of Days (== Dates) are in one week and add a page break after each week.

To make my problem more clear, here's the relevant code first:

```
{% for day in plan.Days %}
   ...
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="footnote">
                <td>** Debug:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Index:  {{forloop.index}}, DateTypeChoice: {{plan.DateTypeChoice }}</td> <!-- just debug-statements -->
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    {% assign endofweek = forloop.index | modulo: plan.DateTypeChoice %}
    <p>endofweek: {{endofweek}}</p>
    {%if endofweek == 0 %}
    <p>"dubididu Index: " {{forloop.index}}</p>
    <div style="page-break-before: always"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

`plan.DateTypeChoice`is an integer-value containing the number of days of a week (5 or 7 days). It is defined in my Drop-Model as

```
    public int DateTypeChoice { get; set; }
```

Now in my test-scenario, the debug-statements (`Index` and `DateTypeChoice`) are showing the values I expect, but actually `endofweek` contains for example (see below) `5` instead of `0`and I don't know why it is.

example output is:

```
** Debug:
Index:  5, DateTypeChoice: 5
endofweek: 5 // This should be 0 imho
```

I also tried to put brackets to the assignment, like

```
    {% assign endofweek = (forloop.index | modulo: plan.DateTypeChoice) %}
```

but then I get an error thrown (value can'T be NULL).

I hope someone could help me out here. Perhaps I am using modulo wrong? As I know, forloop.index is a numeric value and numeric values given to the template from the model are treated as numeric values by the parser, too, so I am out of ideas.

**Edit:**

Based on [this](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/liquid-not-honouring-calculations-in-assign-statement-142643) thread, I tried it with capturing instead of assigning, but same result. Code:

```
{% capture endofweek %} {{ forloop.index | modulo: plan.DateTypeChoice }}{% endcapture %}

    <p>"endofweek: " {{endofweek}}</p> //again 5 :-(
    {%if endofweek == 0 %}
```

Help is really appreciated here :-)

Comment: Hmm, I remember filters don't work with `assign` tags. And IIRC, `capture` values are always strings. Not sure if this will work, but you could try using the filter inline in your `if` tag: `{%if (forloop.index | modulo: plan.DateTypeChoice) == 0 %}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried it, and weird as is, it is always(!) hit, not only every 5th time or so. although IN the if condition, I output the same calculation and it shows me it is NOT 0. very weird behaviour. Also, I tried adding just the plain old `{{ 3 | modulo:2 }} ` as copied out of the liquid-docs somewhere in my template, but instead of `1` i get `3`. Seems that the filter is just not applied and so the parser uses only the first argument. I created a post in the google group for dotliquid and hope someone there can help. For now, I think I have to refactor my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution...

After re-analyzing, I found out that literally *no* filter was applied in my templates. That said, I found a solution right [here](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/103).

I'm using the

Template.NamingConvention = new DotLiquid.NamingConventions.CSharpNamingConvention();

too, so after changing `modulo:`to `Modulo` with a capital **M**, all works out fine.. *sigh*